# Terminating a Process Started with os/exec in Golang

Tags: go

Is there a way to terminate a process started with os.exec in Golang? For example (from http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_Start),

```
cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "5")
err := cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
log.Printf("Waiting for command to finish...")
err = cmd.Wait()
log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
```

Is there a way to terminate that process ahead of time, perhaps after 3 seconds?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Run and terminate an `exec.Process`:

```
// Start a process:
cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "5")
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Kill it:
if err := cmd.Process.Kill(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal("failed to kill process: ", err)
}
```

Run and terminate an `exec.Process` after a timeout:

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3 * time.Second)
defer cancel()

if err := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "sleep", "5").Run(); err != nil {
    // This will fail after 3 seconds. The 5 second sleep
    // will be interrupted.
}
```

*See this example in the [Go docs](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#example-CommandContext)*

---

**Legacy**

*Before Go 1.7, we didn't have the `context` package and this answer was different.*

Run and terminate an `exec.Process` after a timeout using channels and a goroutine:

```
// Start a process:
cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "5")
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Wait for the process to finish or kill it after a timeout (whichever happens first):
done := make(chan error, 1)
go func() {
    done <- cmd.Wait()
}()
select {
case <-time.After(3 * time.Second):
    if err := cmd.Process.Kill(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to kill process: ", err)
    }
    log.Println("process killed as timeout reached")
case err := <-done:
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("process finished with error = %v", err)
    }
    log.Print("process finished successfully")
}
```

Either the process ends and its error (if any) is received through `done` or 3 seconds have passed and the program is killed before it's finished.

Comment: Note: after killing the Process, Wait() will return. You should do a pull from done after `err := cmd.Process.Kill()` to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to be more or less what I was looking for.

Comment: thanks for this! Adding a [link to a great tutorial on go channels](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/channels-in-go.html) as it has helped me understand the code in your answer ;-)

Comment: @RhythmicFistman it would cause the goroutine to hang until the end of the program trying to send to done when no one was receiving it. An even better method would be to change the first line to `done := make(chan error, 1)`. This would allow the send to succeed immediately and the goroutine to exit without a pull on done.

Comment: Ah, thanks. The 1 deep channel seems to be the go timeout idiom, so I'll go with that.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg Sorry if this is very obvious, but how does `make(chan err, 1)` fix memory leaks and allows the go routine to exit cleanly?

Comment: @CharlieParker, that ensures that one send to the channel will always succeed immediately and the sender can move on or, in this case, exit. If not, then it will wait for someone to receive. If no one ever does, it will wait forever and hold the memory.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg So one could also use non-blocking write to chan which IMO might be less prone to future mistakes... e.g. if someone makes bug and sends twice to  make(chan error, 1) it will again block. Here is non-blocking example: http://play.golang.org/p/OP-eZ8hS1k

Comment: @KamilDziedzic, the purpose of the write to done is to ensure the program has quit (wait returned) before continuing with the program. Under no circumstance can the program continue to run after that select statement. If you do a non-blocking write, that won't be guarenteed.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg I don't get it. It waits exactly like the original code on `cmd.Wait()`, and writing to done might only fail when a) it has full buffer (which it has after sending first value) b) nothing is waiting to receive... and actually this means that probably goroutine might try to send to done before main goroutine will be ready to receive... so, yes, buffered chan is required. http://play.golang.org/p/Mx2gh9zMji But I still don't get why you say it wouldn't wait for cmd to finish

Comment: cmd.Wait() would still wait. The issue is the select statement wouldn't. The select statement could move onto other parts of the code even when the kill didn't work. If the select is in a for loop you could have unbounded memory consumption as it launches and doesn't cleanup processes.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg this solution only kills the main process, is there are any child/grandchild for that process they become orphan after this operation. Is there any way to kill the orphaned processes too. I tried creating a group and then sending a kill signal, but haven't been successful in solving it yet.

Comment: @Zippoxer you should update your answer to remove the pull from `done` in the first select case.  You don't need it since you are creating a buffered channel in line 1.

Comment: @RyanWalls As Stephen clarified in the first comment, we better pull from done to wait for .Wait() to return. As far as I can recall, I made a buffered channel to let the goroutine exit as soon as .Wait() returns. I see no other implications to that.

Comment: @Zippoxer based on Stephen's 2nd comment, the `done` pull is not necessary if you use a buffered channel.  Quoting: "An even better method would be to change the first line to `done := make(chan error, 1)`. This would allow the send to succeed immediately and the goroutine to exit without a pull on `done`"

Comment: @RyanWalls I see it now. The goroutine sending to `done` would exit as soon as `cmd.Wait()` returns and won't have to hang until it's message is received since `done` is a buffered channel. Thanks ;-)

Comment: What to do when the command is run by root, something like exec.Command("sudo yes")

Comment: @arvind.mohan Try `exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "sudo echo yes")`

Comment: Hi Moshe, but the child process will still be alive, no?

Comment: There is a problem with this solution: sometimes you will call Kill() on a process that already finished and it will return "os: process already finished" error and your program will fail, when nothing critical actually happened.

Comment: @Fefer_Ivan If the process is finished, `select` should enter the `err := <-done` case which doesn't `Kill()` the process, don't you think? Though I could imagine an edge case where the Go scheduler switches goroutines after `cmd.Wait()` returns (the process is finished) but before it sent to the `done` channel, causing the timeout case to be executed. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: How to do to get stdout/stderr when command is finished ?
I want start the exec command but after, I want run a goroutine to set the result in a variable. Also I want to stop kill the command in an antoher goroutine

Answer (score 27):

The other answers are right about calling `Kill()`, but the parts regarding killing the process after a timeout are little outdated now.

This can be done now with the `context` package and [exec.CommandContext](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#CommandContext) (example adapted from the example in the docs):

```
func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 100*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel()

    if err := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "sleep", "5").Run(); err != nil {
        // This will fail after 100 milliseconds. The 5 second sleep
        // will be interrupted.
    }
}
```

From the docs:

> The provided context is used to kill the process (by calling os.Process.Kill) if the context becomes done before the command completes on its own.

After the `Run()` completes, you can inspect `ctx.Err()`. If the timeout was reached, the type of the error returned will be [DeadLineExceeded](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#pkg-variables). If it's `nil`, check the `err` returned by `Run()` to see if the command completed without errors.

Answer (score 9):

A simpler version without select and channels.

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("cat", "/dev/urandom")
    cmd.Start()
    timer := time.AfterFunc(1*time.Second, func() {
        err := cmd.Process.Kill()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err) // panic as can't kill a process.
        }
    })
    err := cmd.Wait()
    timer.Stop()

    // read error from here, you will notice the kill from the 
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

> Well, after consulting some experienced go programmer, this is apparently not a GOly enough way to solve the problem. So please refer to the accepted answer.

---

Here is an even shorter version, and very straight forward. BUT, possibly having tons of hanging goroutines if timeout is long.

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("cat", "/dev/urandom")
    cmd.Start()
    go func(){
        time.Sleep(timeout)
        cmd.Process.Kill()
    }()
    return cmd.Wait()
}
```

Answer (score 7):

While `exec.CommandContext` is very convenient and works fine in most cases, I had some issues with  the process' children staying alive - which resulted in `cmd.Wait()` hanging.

If someone encounters a similar situation, here's how I solved the issue.

1. Request process group to be created before starting the command using `Setpgid`
2. Start a go routine that will kill the **process group** upon timeout

Naive example (for readability):

```
cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "5")

// Request the OS to assign process group to the new process, to which all its children will belong
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}

go func() {
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    // Send kill signal to the process group instead of single process (it gets the same value as the PID, only negative)
    syscall.Kill(-cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL) 
}

err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
log.Printf("Command finished successfully")
```

A bit nicer example (can be less intuitive for new Gophers):

```
    // Create a context with timeout, which will close ctx.Done() channel upon timeout
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
    defer cancel() // Make sure the context is canceled, which will close ctx.Done() channel on function exit
    cmd := exec.Command("sleep", "5")

    // Request the OS to assign process group to the new process, to which all its children will belong
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{Setpgid: true}

    go func() {
        // Wait until timeout or deferred cancellation
        <- ctx.Done()

        // Send kill signal to the process group instead of single process (it gets the same value as the PID, only negative)
        _ = syscall.Kill(-cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGKILL)
    }()

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("Command finished successfully")
```

P.S. For brevity, I replaced `cmd.Start` + `cmd.Wait` with `cmd.Run`

Comment: Thanks man, I've started a bash script (which has pipeline inside) from go and I was wondering why some resources haven't released. Your solution helped!