# Force to close SSH client session

Tags: go, ssh

I've written a SSH client to connect to network devices and I set a timeout through "select" once the running command takes more than 25 seconds. I noticed a few of devices that they have another IOS it can not drop the SSH session w/ them through Close() method once the timeout has been triggered and it causes goroutinge leaking. I need to keep up the client and disconnect the session to be ready for next command. looks the goroutine doesn't terminate for ever at that time!  Do you guys have any idea?

```
    go func() {
       r <- s.Run(cmd)
    }()

    select {
       case err := <-r:
         return err
       case <-time.After(time.Duration(timeout) * time.Second):
         s.Close()
         return fmt.Errorf("timeout after %d seconds", timeout)
    }
```

Through the heap profiling I saw the below:
    2.77GB 99.44% 99.44%     2.77GB 99.44%  bytes.makeSlice

```
     0     0% 99.44%     2.77GB 99.44%  bytes.(*Buffer).ReadFrom

     0     0% 99.44%     2.77GB 99.44%  golang.org/x/crypto/ssh.(*Session).start.func1

     0     0% 99.44%     2.77GB 99.44%  golang.org/x/crypto/ssh.(*Session).stdout.func1

     0     0% 99.44%     2.77GB 99.44%  io.Copy

     0     0% 99.44%     2.77GB 99.44%  io.copyBuffer

     0     0% 99.44%     2.78GB 99.93%  runtime.goexit
```

ROUTINE ======================== runtime.goexit in /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s

```
     0     2.78GB (flat, cum) 99.93% of Total

     .          .   1993:   RET

     .          .   1994:

     .          .   1995:// The top-most function running on a goroutine

     .          .   1996:// returns to goexit+PCQuantum.

     .          .   1997:TEXT runtime·goexit(SB),NOSPLIT,$0-0

     .     2.78GB   1998:   BYTE    $0x90   // NOP

     .          .   1999:   CALL    runtime·goexit1(SB) // does not return

     .          .   2000:   // traceback from goexit1 must hit code range of goexit

     .          .   2001:   BYTE    $0x90   // NOP

     .          .   2002:


     .          .   2003:TEXT runtime·prefetcht0(SB),NOSPLIT,$0-8
```

Comment: Is the `r` channel buffered? When you timeout there's no receiver to accept the result from `s.Run`. You may still need to actually kill the remote process; have you tried using `s.Signal` to kill it when it times out?

Comment: Yes I tried s.Signal(ssh.SIGKILL) but nothing happened! I have this issue for few of devices not all.

Comment: Again, is `r` buffered?

Comment: that's not buffered, I tried w/ buffed but same.

Comment: I noticed the io.copy freezes at below blocks once i try to close session. https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/ssh/session.go#L468-L492

Comment: It needs to be buffered or the goroutine can't return.

Comment: Don't close the session to abort, kill the process and Wait on it (Run is calling Wait for you)

Comment: can you explain me why we need buffered channel here?

Comment: the goroutine can't return until the send on `r` completes. You can either buffer the channel and ignore the value, or receive again after the timeout.

Comment: I believe the process triggered by s.Run is not properly stoped, hence it cannot deallocate the resource. have you tried to send sigterm/sig kill to that process? https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Session.Signal

and instead of Run, use Start and wait  like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886531/terminating-a-process-started-with-os-exec-in-golang

Comment: @ahmy You should turn that into a full answer. Calling Start and then Wait is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Channel `r` blocks the Go routine from returning, as it is not being emptied. I've written an adapted version of your code and inserted a Wait group to demonstrate the problem:

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup // This is only added for demonstration purposes
    s := new(clientSession)

    r := make(chan error)

    go func(s *clientSession) {
        wg.Add(1)
        r <- s.Run()
        wg.Done() // Will only be called after s.Run() is able to return
    }(s)

    fmt.Println("Client has been opened")

    select {
    case err := <-r:
        fmt.Println(err)
    case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
        s.Close()
        fmt.Println("Timed out, closing")
    }

    wg.Wait() // Waits until wg.Done() is called.

    fmt.Println("Main finished successfully")
}
```

Go playground seems to terminate the program, so I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/muhlemmer/6afde02aeb195dae74e6e78365f18b03) with the complete run-able code. When we run [`incorrect.go`](https://gist.github.com/muhlemmer/6afde02aeb195dae74e6e78365f18b03#file-incorrect-go):

```
$ go run incorrect.go
Client has been opened
Timed out, closing
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
....
```

That's because our code is deadlocked on the `wg.Wait()` line. This demonstrated that `wg.Done()` in the Go routine was never reached.

As the comments point out, a buffered channel can help out here. But only if you don't care about the error anymore, after calling `s.Close()`

```
r := make(chan error, 1)
```

[`buffered.go`](https://gist.github.com/muhlemmer/6afde02aeb195dae74e6e78365f18b03#file-buffered-go) runs correctly, but the error is lost:

```
$ go run buffered.go
Client has been opened
Timed out, closing
Main finished successfully
```

Another option would be to drain the channel exactly 1 time:

```
select {
    case err := <-r:
        fmt.Println(err)
    case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
        s.Close()
        fmt.Println("Timed out, closing")
        fmt.Println(<-r)
    }
```

Or by wrapping `select` in a `for` loop (without buffered channel):

```
X:
    for {
        select {
        case err := <-r:
            fmt.Println(err)
            break X // because we are in main(). Normally `return err`
        case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
            s.Close()
            fmt.Println("Timed out, closing")
        }
    }
```

When we run [`drain.go`](https://gist.github.com/muhlemmer/6afde02aeb195dae74e6e78365f18b03#file-drain-go) we see the error also printed:

```
$ go run incorrect.go
Client has been opened
Timed out, closing
Run() closed
Main finished successfully
```

In real world, one would be running multiple Go routines. So you will want to use some counters on the `for` loop or further utilize Wait group functionality.