# Go os/exec Command.Start() twice in a row

Tags: go, exec, system-calls

I'm trying to use Go's **os/exec** `Command()` to **simulate a keypress**, and sometimes I'll want to use this keypress multiple times in *quick succession*. I'm using `exec.Command` to call ["xte"](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/xte.1.html), "key XF86AudioPlay", which pauses music on a Linux OS. While the `Command` can `Start()` *or* `Run()` no problem, if I try to execute again, I get an error:

```
exec: already started
```

I've tried using `Process.Kill()` immediately after the execution, in order to free it up, but this will make the execution not work in the first place. I got this idea from here: [Terminating a Process Started with os/exec in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886531/terminating-a-process-started-with-os-exec-in-golang)

My code uses a `switch` and calls this pause function accordingly, but I'll simply share the basis of the code I wrote, with the `case` as an example function:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("xte", "key XF86AudioPlay")
//...
func Pause() {
        err := cmd.Start() // or cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        err = cmd.Process.Kill()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Failed to kill: %s", err)
        }
}
```

So, to recap, I'm successful at calling it one time, but upon success calls to `Pause()`, I get the error from `cmd.Start()`/`Run()` which read: `exec: already started`.

I also tried going *lower*, that is, using `syscall`, but I ran into some trouble. I tried:

```golang
args[0] = "xte"
args[1] = "key"
args[2] = "XF86AudioPlay"
//... Pause():
            err := syscall.Exec("/bin", args, os.Environ())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
```

And here I got a `permission denied` error, even running as super user (sudo).

How should I proceed call this `Command()` and then free it up for immediate *recall*? Or am I on the right track with `syscall`?

**Edit**
So the solution as both Amd and Son Bui state, was to *create* the `Command` everytime I intend to call it, basically putting the assignment `cmd := exec.Command()`*inside* my `Pause()` method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the `type Cmd struct {` Docs said:

> A Cmd cannot be reused after calling its Run, Output or CombinedOutput
>   methods.

---

1- Use two separate `exec.Command` like this,
Also you may need some delay between runs (simulating two separate keystrokes):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    Pause()
    fmt.Println("Once")
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    Pause()
    fmt.Println("Twice")
}
func Pause() {
    cmd := exec.Command("xte", "key XF86AudioPlay")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

---

2- You may run it once:

You may use something like this (not tested):

```
xte 'key XF86AudioPlay' 'key XF86AudioPlay'
```

and consider adding a short delay to the xte command (simulating two separate keystrokes):

```
xte 'key XF86AudioPlay' 'usleep 100000' 'key XF86AudioPlay'
```

Like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    Pause()
    fmt.Println("Once")
}
func Pause() {
    cmd := exec.Command("xte", `key XF86AudioPlay`, `usleep 100000`, `key XF86AudioPlay`)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

---

See:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/499926/why-do-these-xte-commands-work-in-terminal-but-not-when-bound-with-xbindkeys

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/xte.1.html

http://wiki.robotz.com/index.php/Linux_Tools_to_Remap_Keys_and_Mouse_Buttons

---

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

See from source code:

cmd struct: (https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go line 99)

```
// Process is the underlying process, once started.
Process *os.Process
```

And in `Start` function (https://golang.org/src/os/exec/exec.go line 327)
:

```
if c.Process != nil {
    return errors.New("exec: already started")
}
```

So you can only use cmd.Start once time. If you want to use multiple time, you can create new Cmd OR run multiple command in once, ex:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/sh", "-c", "command1; command2; command3; ...")
```