# How do I stop a NewScanner Scan() after a timeout in background if there is no new output in tailed process

Tags: go, buffer

The newScanner.Scan() function is waiting for the input indefinitely. How can I stop the scan() function and just exit out from the process after some amount of time ***if there is not output from tailed process***?

> So if there is no output from the process which is tailed, a timer
>   should get initiated to 5mins. Post 5mins, still if no output from
>   scan() function then it should exit out from TailProcess function. But
>   lets say at 4.59 mins, there was output then the timer should get
>   cleared to 0.

```
func ExecuteCommand(FILEPATH string) (*exec.Cmd) {
    cmd := exec.Command("decode_utility", FILEPATH, "4", "1")
    return cmd;
}

func TailProcess(c *exec.Cmd) {

    out, err := c.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ERROR in piping the output to stdout: ", err)
    }
    c.Stderr = c.Stdout

    if err := c.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ERROR in starting of the command: ", err)
    }

    s := bufio.NewScanner(out)
    s.Split(bufio.ScanLines)

    for s.Scan(); {
        line := s.Text()
        fields := strings.Fields(line)
        fmt.Printf("Fields: %q", fields)
    }

    if s.Err() != nil && s.Err() != io.EOF {
        log.Fatal("ERROR in scanning of the output: ", s.Err())
    }

    if err := c.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Exiting the command due to long wait: ", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: See also https://gobyexample.com/timeouts for a simple example.

Comment: Kill the process to exit the scanner. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886531/terminating-a-process-started-with-os-exec-in-golang

Comment: Hi @Marc Yes it answered but that is just timeout after t seconds even if there is output in the tailed process. My Question was if there is no output in scan() and scan() is waiting for some more input till t seconds, then after t seconds it should kill but before let's say t-1 seconds a new line comes, then it should clear the timeout and start a new one.

Comment: @Tethys0 In Go it is simple: Read the documentation to bufio.Scanner. Is there a mention of a timeout? Yes: You can use it. No: There is no such thing, not even a hidden one or a magic one. bufio.Scanner does not offer what you want. Maybe write your own TimeoutReader which does that, and wrap `out` in such one?

Comment: @Marc I have corrected my question. Please check.

Comment: @Volker yes forsure. That is the last resort of every developer. If you cannot find a solution, build one. But I asked the community just to be sure, if there are any workarounds for it. Because there should be.. I don't find any reason not to kill the process (or return from the function) if the scan() goes in loop indefinitely. There should be a solution for this definitely.

Comment: @Tethys0 Killing the child process is the proper solution to the problem, not a workaround. The child process should be killed one way or another.  Killing the child process cause the Scan loop to break.